# mysqlimport imports NULL values unwantedly as int 0

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, import, export

I would like to understand how to create a decent back-up file by using `mysql` and `mysqlimport`. I know that I can use `mysqldump` and `mysql`, but I'm learning to use the combination: `mysql` and `mysqlimport`.

I'm on mysql5.7.21 in Windows 10.
I have test table: aircrafts that looks like this:

[image]

I would like to export this table to a textfile trough the `mysql` client tool. 
So I do this:

```
mysql -h localhost -u root -D julian -p -e "SELECT * FROM `aircrafts` " > aircrafts.txt
```

This creates the back-up file, and content of it is:

```
id  countryFactoryID    name    type    price
1   1   Cessna 172 Skyhawk  GA  60000
2   43  Diamond DA40    GA  NULL
3   1   Cirrus SR20 GA  NULL
4   1   Piper PA-28 Cherokee    GA  NULL
5   1   Beechcraft A23 Musketeer    GA  NULL
6   1   Grumman American AA-5 Traveller GA  NULL
```

What I noticed about the back-up file is that it uses `NULL` instead of `\N`.
But that's ok I guess.

Next, I import the back-up file like this:

`mysqlimport --local -l -v --ignore-lines=1 -p -u root myDB aircrafts.txt`

The output in CLI is:

```
Connecting to localhost
Selecting database myDB
Locking tables for write
Loading data from LOCAL file: aircrafts.txt into aircrafts
myDB.aircrafts: Records: 6  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 6
Disconnecting from localhost
```

Ok, so far so good.

When I look in phpmyadmin, then I see this:

[image]

As you can see, the price is `0`, but I would like to have a NULL-value, like in the first image. It's strange because my default value for column price is NULL.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It is best, when at all possible, to use text instead of images for the reasons outlined in this [link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/470530).

Comment: more info on import NULL values: [mysql load null values from csv data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675323/mysql-load-null-values-from-csv-data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried Nikita's answer. So I used the mysql command like this:

```
mysql -h localhost -u root -D julian -p -e "SELECT id, countryFactoryID, name, type, IFNULL(price, '\\N') AS price FROM `aircrafts` " > aircrafts.txt
```

The result was:

```
id  countryFactoryID    name    type    price
1   1   Cessna 172 Skyhawk  GA  60000
2   43  Diamond DA40    GA  \\N
3   1   Cirrus SR20 GA  \\N
4   1   Piper PA-28 Cherokee    GA  \\N
5   1   Beechcraft A23 Musketeer    GA  \\N
6   1   Grumman American AA-5 Traveller GA  \\N
```

Well ...  this is not what I want; the escaping is erroneous.

So I had to use `SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE`.

```
mysql -h localhost -u root -p -D julian -e "SELECT * INTO OUTFILE 'aircrafts.txt' FROM aircrafts;"
```

The content of aircrafts.txt:

```
1   1   Cessna 172 Skyhawk  GA  60000
2   43  Diamond DA40    GA  \N
3   1   Cirrus SR20 GA  \N
4   1   Piper PA-28 Cherokee    GA  \N
5   1   Beechcraft A23 Musketeer    GA  \N
6   1   Grumman American AA-5 Traveller GA  \N
```

Hooray it works!

Read more about it over here:

https://medium.com/@julek23/how-to-create-an-database-export-with-select-into-outfile-f10983a22db1

Answer (score 1):

This issue is caused by the way MySQL LOAD DATA handles NULLs:

> Handling of NULL values varies according to the FIELDS and LINES
>   options in use:
>
> For the default FIELDS and LINES values, NULL is written as a field
>   value of \N for output, and a field value of \N is read as NULL for
>   input (assuming that the ESCAPED BY character is ).
>
> If FIELDS ENCLOSED BY is not empty, a field containing the literal
>   word NULL as its value is read as a NULL value. This differs from the
>   word NULL enclosed within FIELDS ENCLOSED BY characters, which is read
>   as the string 'NULL'.
>
> If FIELDS ESCAPED BY is empty, NULL is written as the word NULL.
>
> With fixed-row format (which is used when FIELDS TERMINATED BY and
>   FIELDS ENCLOSED BY are both empty), NULL is written as an empty
>   string. This causes both NULL values and empty strings in the table to
>   be indistinguishable when written to the file because both are written
>   as empty strings. If you need to be able to tell the two apart when
>   reading the file back in, you should not use fixed-row format.

In your case NULL is considered as word 'NULL' and if you try to cast 'NULL' to number it will return 0. You need to change NULL to \N or enclose strings using some character.

Comment: It is NULL in the backup-file because `mysql -h localhost -u root -D julian -p -e "SELECT * FROM \`aircrafts\` " > aircrafts.txt` does it like that. Is it possible to convert `NULL` to `\N` in the `mysql` command so a text-editor won't have to do the replacement? Maybe a flag? I wouldn't find it in the manual.

Comment: SELECT id, countryFactoryID, name, type, IFNULL(price, '\\N') AS price

Comment: or use SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE with ENCLOSED BY

Comment: Yes it works with `SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE` thus (`NULL` values become `\N`) but it works differently then `mysql -e "SELECT ..." > file_name`

Comment: @Julian what does happen when you run mysql -e "SELECT id, countryFactoryID, name, type, IFNULL(price, '\\N') AS price ..."?

Comment: Please check my answer: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/262525/105596

Comment: @Julian, you can use select without "into outfile" like you did it in the very beginning

Comment: Please give more information about your whole idea.

Comment: @Julian, mysql -h localhost -u root -D julian -p -e "SELECT id, countryFactoryID, name, type, IFNULL(price, '\\N') AS price FROM `aircrafts` " > aircrafts.txt

Comment: well... you get a `\\N`. For example, a row would look like this: 

`2 43 Diamond DA40 GA \\N`

Comment: @Julian, it will look like this and this is exactly what you need to import correctly: 2 43 Diamond DA40 GA \N

Comment: double "\\" is needed to escape the second \